# Tags of html in DOM model

Tags: java, html, web-applications, dom

Q : `<img>` `<body>` etc. these tags of a html page is a node when it is represented in DOM model in java .

But if the `<img>` tag has address (http://....com/) then what it is?

Is it a node or what in DOM model ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The URL has nothing to do with the DOM. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an attribute of the Node

given a node that is an element, you would do

```
String url = ((Element)imageNode).getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: I don't find getAttribute method in java . Instead I get a getAttributes method which returns nodenamdmap . from nodenamedmap I again find node . I fall in a loop . Is attribute is treated as node in DOM in java???

Comment: sorry, getAttribute is on Element (a subclass of Node), so i will change the example above.

Comment: the interface Attr is a sub interface of Node.

Answer (score 1):

The `img` **element** has a `src` **attribute** with a URI **value**.